# Is there a way to store files on the docker host which will survive host restarts?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am ***not*** looking to save or commit docker images or containers. This is a question on how to save files (e.g., to drive configs which can be volume mounted on docker containers).

I am looking for a way to save files on the docker host filesystem which will survive docker restarts e.g., `boot2docker down` + `boot2docker up`.

Comment: Similar (or even duplicate) with [Share directory or volume with container from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964120/share-directory-or-volume-with-container-from-host) and [
In Docker, how do I share a volume from a container to a host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561395/in-docker-how-do-i-share-a-volume-from-a-container-to-a-host) or [
How to deal with persistent storage (e.g. databases) in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496940/how-to-deal-with-persistent-storage-e-g-databases-in-docker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be using volumes ([`docker volumes create/ls/...`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)):

- Those volumes can be [mounted by containers (`--volumes-from`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems), part of the `disk.vmdk` which is the boot2docker VM disk stored on host.
- And they are persisted in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. That will survive a boot2docker session (`docker-machine stop/start`)

If you really need to backup them directly on the host (outside the virtual disk), you can copy `/var/lib/docker/volumes` to `/c/Users/...` (or `/Users/...`).
A `docker volume ls` combined with [`docker volume inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) will list the folders within `/var/lib/docker/volumes` that you need to consider for backup.

Comment: I am on a slightly older version of boot2docker and cannot consider upgrade/update to docker-machine (i.e., in docker toolbox). Is there a way to do this on a docker client version 1.7.0 and boot2docker version 1.7.0 ?

Comment: No, just copying the most recent docker-machine and doing a docker-machine upgrade a machine is enough to get you up to date.

Comment: I just went ahead and created a dir + the files under /mnt/.... This is just a workaround... It survives b2d restarts. I have one manual step to cp -R from there everytime there is a restart and might include in Dockerfile. For now, in the lab setup I can live with this manual step.